# getAttribute return value when it does not exist

Tags: javascript, string, null, setattribute

I use `setAttribute` to store some info on an element, so later I can restore the value to its `innerHTML`.
My question is what exactly `element.getAttribute("attr")` return value will be when the attribute does not set (exist)?
It seems that it returns null in chrome (which is good for me), but I read it can return empty string too, but I want to use the value if empty string is set.

so I can't do this obviously:

```
var value = element.getAttribute("prev_value");
if (value) { // won't cover the empty string case, so I need value != null
}
```

Are there any browsers which do not returns null ?

Comment: if (value) covers empty string case actually

Comment: How about not using invalid attributes at all, but stick with [datasets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: If you really want to use attributes you should check [hasAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute).

Comment: You can use `element.hasAttribute()` to check if element has attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Basic usage of getAttribute()

"getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string); see Notes for details."
[- MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

As @Maciej pointed out, you should use .hasAttribute() to return your truthy value.

Answer (score 2):

You should just use a typeof and see if it is an empty string

```
var value = element.getAttribute("prev_value");
if (typeof value == "string" && value.length) {
//..do something
}
```

But, actually making `if("")` returns false, same as `if(null)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Element.getAttribute returns null or empty string if the attribute does not exist

```
if (object.getAttribute("prev_value") === null) {
//data attribute doesn't exist
 }else{
 //data attribute exists
}
```

Internet Explorer, browsers based on Gecko, browsers based on KHTML and not yet public releases of Opera all return null.